# Returning Uint8Array or Uint16Array from Rust with wasm-bindgen

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen, uint8array

I want to expose a Rust library function to JavaScript that may return `&[u8]` *or* `&[u16]` depending on some condition. What's the most robust and performant way to do that?

I've come up with two possible solutions:

#### Solution 1: Just returning a Uint8Array

With this approach, I transmute `&[u16]` to `&[u8]` and then turn it into a `Uint16Array` on the JS side:

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn my_function() -> Uint8Array {
    // Pseudo-code
    match some_condition {
        IsU8 => rust_lib_function().into(),
        IsU16 => {
            unsafe { Uint8Array::view(&rust_lib_function().align_to().1) }
        }
    }
}
```

Afaik I need to be aware of endianess since JS `TypedArrays` are platform endian. That's why I'm using `dataView.getUint16` with `littleEndian` explicitly set to true (because WebAssembly is using Little Endian, correct?).

```js
const uint8Array = my_function();
const dataView = new DataView(uint8Array.buffer, uint8Array.byteOffset, uint8Array.byteLength);
const length = uint8Array.byteLength / Uint16Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;
const uint16Array = new Uint16Array(length);

for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  uint16Array[i] = dataView.getUint16(i * Uint16Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, true /* littleEndian */);
}
```

#### Solution 2: Providing two separate functions

I could also provide two separate versions for `my_function` that I could call depending on some condition. This would require the JS side to check the condition first.

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn my_function_u8() -> Uint8Array {
    match some_condition {
        IsU8 => rust_lib_function().into(),
        IsU16 => {
            panic!("Call my_function_u16");
        }
    }
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn my_function_u16() -> Uint16Array {
    match some_condition {
        IsU16 => rust_lib_function().into(),
        IsU8 => {
            panic!("Call my_function_u8");
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a simpler/more performant solution than the provided ones? Personally I prefer solution 1 since it's easier to maintain in the long term but I don't know if there are any issues with this approach. Since this function is going to be called very often I want to do as less copying as possible.

Comment: I believe [issue 2088](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/issues/2088) is relevant. Unfortunately, the issue seems pretty inactive, so the prettiest method right now is probably to just return a `JsValue`.

Comment: Yes, enums would be great. When returning `JsValue` I would have to create the `Uint8Array`/`Unit16Array` manually, right?

Btw: I went with solution 2 now since it's way less error prone despite being more code duplicated.